# Problems created a SOAP::Lite Perl Web Services Client

Tags: perl, soap, soap-client

I'm using SOAP::Lite to create a web services client.  The first XML packet is what the Java Testing GUI sends.  It receives the correct response.

The second is the XML packet my Perl client is sending (according to SOAP::Lite debug output) and the response I'm receiving from the server is that all of the inputted arguments (hostnameFQ, etc) are empty.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Header/>

<S:Body>
    <ns2:postEvent xmlns:ns2="http://ws.health.server/">
        <hostnameFQ>a</hostnameFQ>
        <eventLabel>b</eventLabel>
        <deviceInst>c</deviceInst>
        <severity>d</severity>
        <message>e</message>
        <eventSource>f</eventSource>
    </ns2:postEvent>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<soap:Body>
    <postEvent xmlns="http://ws.health.server/">
        <hostnameFQ>a</hostnameFQ>
        <eventLabel>b</eventLabel>
        <deviceInst>c</deviceInst>
        <severity>d</severity>
        <message>e</message>
        <eventSource>f</eventSource>
    </postEvent>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

They look the same to me...so I'm not quite sure what is going on.

Here is my Perl code, in case this is helpful:

```
my $EVENT_LISTENER_PROXY = "http://localhost:8080/EventListener/EventListener"; 

my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new( proxy => $EVENT_LISTENER_PROXY);
$soap->on_action( sub { "http://ws.health.server/#postEvent" });
$soap->autotype(0);
$soap->default_ns('http://ws.health.server/');

my $som = $soap->call("postEvent",
SOAP::Data->name('hostnameFQ')->value( "a" ),
SOAP::Data->name('eventLabel')->value( "b" ),
SOAP::Data->name('deviceInst')->value( "c" ),
SOAP::Data->name('severity')->value( "d" ),
SOAP::Data->name('message')->value( "e" ),
SOAP::Data->name('eventSource')->value( "f" )
);
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for some reason the server didn't like the XML input using a default namespace value.  I changed:

```
$soap->default_ns('http://ws.health.server/');
```

to

```
$soap->ns('http://ws.health.server/');
```

And it worked.